geometry and perimeter
Triangle ABC is right-angled at C and is divided into two right-angled triangles by the height relative to C. The radii of the two inscribed circles are 24 cm and 45 cm. What is the perimeter of triangle ABC?
enter image description here


Angle $C$ is apparently not a right angle…

The question as written does not make sense with your drawing. But if you replace $C$ by $A$ in your question, then consider that $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle CAD \sim \triangle ABC$. Since the circles are inscribed, they too are "similar" with the same ratio: we have that $\frac{AD}{BD} = \frac{r_2}{r_1} = \frac{15}{8}$ (ratios of the short legs is equal to the ratio of the radii of the inscribed circles). This shows that $\triangle ABC, \triangle ABD, \triangle CAD$ are all similar to the 8-15-17 right triangle.
To finish the problem, we note that for the 8-15-17 right triangle, the inradius is $r = \frac{(8) (15)}{8 + 15 + 17} = 3$. Then $AB = \frac{r_1}{r} (17) = 136$, since $AB$ is the hypotenuse of $\triangle ABD$. Then the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ is $\frac{40}{8} AB = (5) (136) = \boxed{680}$, since $AB$ is the short leg of $\triangle ABC$.
